# SVN server with svn+ssh protocol over custom port

Tags: ssh, ssh-tunnel, svn, vmware-vcloud-director

I am running Ubuntu 12.04.2 LTS as virtual machine and there is vShield also at the front with enabled firewall and some NAT modifications. There are also other machines in my VPS configuration, but it is not important right know. Important is that I changed SSH port on Ubuntu from 22 to 765 and on the vShield I made port translation from 424 to 765.
Firewall has all the necessary permissions for SSH (and SVN).

So I make SSH conection like this

```
kopparberg:Webpage marek$ ssh marko@91.***.***.69 -p 424
```

and it works like a charm.

Where is the problem?
I am trying to set up SVN server on Ubuntu following this guide http://odyniec.net/articles/ubuntu-subversion-server/.

If checkout my repository "Webpage" over SVN protocol

```
kopparberg:Webpage marek$ svn checkout svn://91.***.***.69/Webpage --username svnuser
```

it works as it should.

What I really want to do, is checkout over **svn+ssh** protocol. I tried many different ways without success.

```
kopparberg:Webpage marek$ svn checkout svn+ssh://91.***.***.69:424/usr/local/svn/repos/Webpage --username svnuser
svn: To better debug SSH connection problems, remove the -q option from 'ssh' in the [tunnels] section of your Subversion configuration file.
svn: Network connection closed unexpectedly
```

Another attempt...

```
kopparberg:Webpage marek$ svn checkout svn+ssh://91.***.***.69/usr/local/svn/repos/Webpage -p 424 --username svnuser
svn: invalid option character: p
Type 'svn help' for usage.
```

I also add `ssh = ssh -p 424` to `/user/marek/.subversion/config` file.

```
kopparberg:Webpage marek$ svn checkout svn+ssh://91.***.***.69/usr/local/svn/repos/Webpage --username svnuser
marek@91.***.***.69's password
Permission denied, please try again.:
```

None of my password is right.

Is it even possible to checkout with **svn+ssh** protocol over custom port without modifiying the config file?

---

EDIT: I found out that I should use SSH user and not SVN user of course. But I was using it on completely wrong way. Instead of `--username` subcommand I should put my username in front of IP address.

```
kopparberg:Webpage marek$ svn checkout svn+ssh://marko@91.***.***.69/usr/local/svn/repos/Webpage
```

This looks much better and it works! What I am still searching is a solution where I will not need to edit config file before checkout. In other words I would like to change the SSH port on the fly.

Comment: Why are you trying to use port 424?  You should be using the SSH user, not the svnserver user, for SSH authentication.  What's in the server's auth log when you fail to connect via `svn+ssh` using the `marko` user?

Comment: I am using port 424 because port 22 is denied by the firewall. Yes, the username was completely wrong. Thank you. Please look up my EDIT part of question.

Answer (score 2):

I guess I'm a little late to the party here, but I encountered the exact same issue here, and resolved it.

First, decide on your new default SSH port. This will affect SSH in general (ie: when you want to connect to the server via SSH using command line, putty etc. The port cannot be changed JUST for SVN, unless you want to invoke multiple SSHD server instances, which is beyond the scope of the original question).

So, assuming the following:

- We want everything done over port 123456
- Your server's IP address is 192.168.1.100
- Your router/firewall has opened up port 123456
- Your router/firewall has setup port forwarding for external port 123456 routing to internal port 123456 for host 192.168.1.100

---

Client Side:

Anyhow, first, modify <~/.subversion/config> on the client machine, and under the line titled `[tunnels]`, enter the following line:

```
ssh = ssh -p 123456
```

---

Server Side:

First, you need to setup the new default SSH port. On your SVN server, edit (in the case of Ubuntu) your SVN SERVER config file (note the 'd' after "SSH"):
    sudo vi /etc/ssh/sshd_config

Look for a line beginning with "Port" (by default, it says "Port 22"), and change "22" to "123456". Save and close the file. Now restart the SSHD server:
    sudo restart ssh

Assuming your SVN setup is working like how you already described above, you are set. If you insist on translating the port rather than just keeping it intact as a single-port-forward-passthrough rule, just change the SSH port used on the server side in , and you're set. I have tested the above setup from a client outside my LAN successfully via:

```
svn --username megaman ls svn+ssh://megaman@DrWileysFortress.dyndns.org/usr/local/svn/repos/private
```

Hope this helps!